# Termux - Error when i want acess to directory

Tags: directory, cd, termux

When i write "cd/" for to acess directory

the response is "bash: cd/: No such file or directory"

How i do to solution this?

Comment: It’s `cd /` (with a space in between the `cd` and the `/`)

Comment: Thanks You, but i finished problem